# How to render not found template in error action Ember

Tags: ember.js

Im trying to render the 404 template(not transitionTo) if I get from backend that record was not found.
I get the error

You passed `controller: 'admin.categories.show'` into the `render` method, but no such controller could be found.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.find('category', params.slug);
  },

  serialize (model) {
    return {
      slug: model.get('slug')
    };
  },

  actions: {
    error: function (error, transition) {
      console.log('error', error, transition);
      this.render('not-found');
    }
  }
```

});

When I try to pass it with controller and into it says

You passed `controller: 'application'` into the `render` method, but no such controller could be found.

```
  this.render('not-found', {
    into: 'application',
    outlet: 'main',
    controller: 'application'
  });
```

Comment: Assuming you are using the Ember.js 2.4, you need to use the hook [renderTemplate()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate) instead of attempting to call this.render() directly.

Comment: You also seem to be following the [Error Substates](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) which from my understanding expects the developer to make use of transitionTo(), so create the appropriate template, and check if Ember.js shows it automatically on a 404. If it does, then you can customize the template to show different errors based on error.status like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692566/emberjs-route-for-model-when-receives-a-404/23695369#23695369.)